# Why can't I show my other forms?

Tags: c#, forms, reference

I have a C# project with 3 forms : Main, AddNewRecord and DeleteRecord. When I try to show the AddNewRecord form from the Main form with the following code, the program show the message :

> The type or namespace "AddNewRecord" could not be found.

This is my code :

```
AddNewRecord frm = new AddNewRecord();
frm.ShowDialog();
```

But when I call the DeleteRecord from AddNewRecord, everything is OK. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Check that AddNewRecord is with public modifier. Please add the rest of the code of AddNewRecord / DeleteRecord. It's all about access modifiers and the right namespace.

Comment: Go to the `AddNewRecord` and check it's namespace. Then call it by complete qualifier like this: `WindowsFormsApplication1.AddNewRecord`

Comment: the simplest would be to put up `using AddNewRecordNamespace;` in your `Main` form `.cs` file

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that the main form is in another Namespace from the others (because i have renamed the project once), but how can i change it without errors